# How to initialize netdevice struct in C?

Tags: c, valgrind

What's the correct way to initialize netdevice struct in C?
I have this function to get local IP address, but I'm getting `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` error in valgrind (also, getting `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` because of this same function).

```
/*
 * Return my IP
 */
char *net_getLocalIp() {
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char *out = calloc(1, 60);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    /* I want IP address attached to "eth0" */
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ - 1);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    close(fd);

    strcpy(out, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) &ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
    return out;
}
```

The function is working fine, I'm getting the correct IP. But I'm getting these errors in valgrind. Is there a correct way to initialize this struct or this is a false-positive from valgrind and I should ignore it?

```
==2469== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2469==    at 0x4C39D1E: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==2469==    by 0x4C3D5F3: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==2469==    by 0x4C6579F: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:114)
==2469==    by 0x4C456BE: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==2469==    by 0x4CF7965: inet_ntoa (inet_ntoa.c:34)
==2469==    by 0x134921: net_getLocalIp (abc_net.c:567)
==2469==    by 0x110399: generateStatusJson (abc_net_aux.c:22)
==2469==    by 0x120E7B: writeJsonToFile (net_io.c:1912)
==2469==    by 0x133445: backgroundTasks (abc.c:207)
==2469==    by 0x10EC72: main (abc.c:409)
==2469==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2469==    at 0x1348B0: net_getLocalIp (abc_net.c:554)
==2469==
==2469== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2469==    at 0x4C39D29: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==2469==    by 0x4C3D5F3: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==2469==    by 0x4C6579F: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:114)
==2469==    by 0x4C456BE: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==2469==    by 0x4CF7965: inet_ntoa (inet_ntoa.c:34)
==2469==    by 0x134921: net_getLocalIp (abc_net.c:567)
==2469==    by 0x110399: generateStatusJson (abc_net_aux.c:22)
==2469==    by 0x120E7B: writeJsonToFile (net_io.c:1912)
==2469==    by 0x133445: backgroundTasks (abc.c:207)
==2469==    by 0x10EC72: main (abc.c:409)
==2469==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2469==    at 0x1348B0: net_getLocalIp (abc_net.c:554)
```

Comment: On my machine there are no valgrind errors. What happens if you call `memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr))`?

Comment: That did the trick, tks!